# Can a K8S node host pods belonging to different namespaces?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Say a K8S node has 2 pods running on it. I know that a K8S node itself does not belong to a namespace. But can the two pods it hosts belong to different namespaces?

Comment: Well, yes, that's the point of namespaces.

Comment: You could try this by setting up a single-node cluster using minikube or kind, creating pods in multiple namespaces (`kube-system` and `default` would be enough), and running `kubectl describe node` on the single node; you will in fact see pods from multiple namespaces on the single node and there's even a column for the namespace in the `kubectl describe node` output.

Answer (score 1):

> But can the two pods it hosts belong to different namespaces?

Yes, nodes can host pods from any namespace. But scheduling of Pods can be restricted in other ways, e.g. using [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/)